# How to share android screen with users outside LAN?

Tags: networking, screenshots, screen-sharing, airdroid

I work as a developer from home and I wish to demo the android app to my boss. He doesn't have an Android phone, so I have to demo the app from my phone and demo all scenarios for him from my android phone.

The question is how do I share the screen with him ?

Here's what I tried ?

1 - [BBQdroid](http://screen.bbqdroid.org/) exactly what I want but it only works in a LAN, in fact I have to specify the android local IP address i.e. 192.168.x.x

2 - [Teamviewer quicksupport](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.quicksupport.market) but it exposes all the apps on my phone and it's not live sharing, I have to keep on sending screenshots.

3 - AirDroid only screenshots, no live sharing of the android screen

Please help me guys find a way to share the android screen live with my boss.

Thanks

Comment: any help anyone please ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use BBQDroid, but it will require additional tweaking on your router.

First, you'll have to find out your IP. This can easily be done by typing "my ip" into Google, which will return your public IP.

Next, you'll need to go into your router settings and add your Android device to the router's DMZ, meaning that all incoming connections get forwarded to your device. 
Find out the model name and brand of your router, then look up instructions on how to access the DMZ.

By this point, your public IP should direct to your phone. Launch BBQDroid on your device and attempt to connect to it using your public IP from another device.

When you're finished, I'd recommend removing your Android device from your router's DMZ, as a security precaution.

Answer (score 0):

Once your screen is showing on your desktop it is easy to share it with others by using Webex, Join.me or Google Hangouts.

Answer (score 0):

BTW - I was able to share my screen by installing Team Viewer to see my Note 4 screen on my Mac.  Then I used Join.me to broadcast it to other to see.